# adding custom property to webpart with a custom toolpart

Tags: sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I'm trying to add a custom property to my webpart as below:

```
        [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
        [WebBrowsable(true)]
        [System.ComponentModel.Category("Settings")]
        [WebDisplayName("RSS List Path")]
        [WebDescription("")]
        public string RSSListURL
        {
            get
            {
                if (_myListURL == null)
                {
                    _myListURL = "http://server2003dev/dev/";
                }
                return _myListURL;
            }
            set { _myListURL = value; }
        }
```

But within the webpart I am also overriding the GetToolParts() method as below with my own custom toolpart:

public override ToolPart[] GetToolParts()
    {

```
    return new ToolPart[] { new RSSCountrySettings(), new WebPartToolPart() };
}
```

I need to display my custom toolpart (RSSCountrySettings) **and** my custom propery (RSS List Path) *under* the catergory Settings.

Any ideas how I do this, I able to only get one but not both to display...?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the base class's toolparts. Try this instead:

```
    public override ToolPart[] GetToolParts()
    {
            var result = new List<ToolPart>() ;
            var toolparts = base.GetToolParts();
            result.AddRange(toolparts.ToList());
            result.Add(new WebPartToolPart());
            return result.ToArray();
    }
```

The reason you need to do this is that the base class generates a toolpart for your custom property. However, you do not allow it to add that toolpart to the toolpart collection. So, you must get the base class's toolparts as a collection, then add yours in there as well. That's the danger in overriding an existing method. Check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584178%28v=office.11%29.aspx) out for more info

Answer (score 0):

You have to add CustomPropertyToolPart to toolParts list. Like this:

```
    public override Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ToolPart[] GetToolParts()
    {
        List<ToolPart> list = new List<ToolPart>();
        list.AddRange(base.GetToolParts());

        // adds custom controls            
        result.Add(new WebPartToolPart()); 

        // adds default controls for properties marked with [WebBrowsable(true)]
        list.Add(new CustomPropertyToolPart()); 
        return list.ToArray();
    }
```